# Zurb Foundation 6 Equalizer new instance on UL element

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 6.4.

I want to create a new instance of Foundation.Equalizer.

My markup is simple. I have an `ul.products` parent and a list of `li.product` children.

I don't have control on the markup, so I can't add the data attributes like `data-equalizer` to the `ul` and `data-equalizer-watch` to each `li`.

Now I'm calling this script:

```
var $products = new Foundation.Equalizer( $( 'ul.products' ) );
```

And I see something is happening on my `ul`. Some data is attached and it became:

```
<ul class="products columns-3" data-resize="2spia2-eq" data-mutate="jzvonv-eq" data-e="fz0751-e" data-events="resize">
```

But the height of `li` children isn't changed. So it's useless. How to complete my script to get Equalizer work properly?

Here the official documentation: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html#javascript-reference

Probably I'm missing something with the options or calling some methods. I'm pretty new to Foundation and Javascript, so everything isn't so clear yet.

Comment: Are your li's inline?

Comment: They are in default `display: list-item;`

Comment: Try different display types, that might be the cause.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I don't see the inline style for the height for each li. Like in default equalizer instance. I'll probably switch to xy grid to solve this kind of issues. Death to float :)

Comment: It would helpful to see your whole code.